# Why won't one image display in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have searched everywhere for an answer and cannot find one. For some reason, in my HTML document, an image will display when opened from my browser fine. But when I upload my site to a server host this one specific image won't show.

Code:

```html
<html>

<body background="images/background.jpg">

<img src="images/pp_4.png" style="float:left" vspace=50>

<center><img src="images/logo.png"></center>

<hr color="pink">

<style>
    @font-face{
    font-family:"chococookie";
    src:url("font/choco_cookie.ttf")
    }

    p{font-family:chococookie; 
    font-size: 100%; }

</style>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<center><img src=""></center>
    <center><p></p></center>

<center><img src=""></center>
    <center><p></p></center>

<center><img src=""></center>
    <center><p></p></center>

<center><img src=""></center>
    <center><p></p></center>

<center><img src="images/image_226.jpg"></center>
    <center><p>Love Live! gone sexy. #anime #sexy #ecchi #lovelive #bikini #chan #tyan #girl #kawaii #cute - 22 Oct at 10:48 pm</p></center>

<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<hr color="pink">

<center><a href="page_46.html"><img src="images/more_images.png" /></a></center>

</html>
```

I have tried resizing the image, and many other things, but nothing worked. The image not displaying is `pp_4.png`.

Comment: You are not specifying a doctype, try to add in order to make your document valid ... and your code is very bad written, you need to re-factor it

Comment: Also `<center>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used. I'm surprised their still teaching that.

Comment: Use CSS to center elements, not `<center>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that image's name uploaded to your server matches name that you have written in your code. I mean, check for uppercase and lowercase letters, as far as you are probably using Windows that doesn't care about letters register. Your server might be using Linux that does care about it

Comment: Thanks, the problem was just as you said. the .png extension was in all caps, once I changed it, the image was displayed. Thanks!

Comment: Always act as if everything is case-sensitive, even if it's not. Deploying on windows `pp_4.png` vs. `pp_4.PNG` would have worked, but if your business or provider changes infrastructure things would "mysteriously" break.  Even if you could get away with it, doing that is a cache-buster. `foo.png` / `foo.Png` / `foo.PNG` are three different files as far as the _cache_ is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure the image was uploaded to the server successfully. Try accessing that image without using your HTML code. For example, if your domain is www.example.com and your images directory is in the root folder, you should be able to access images from URLs such as:

www.example.com/images/image_226.jpg

Try to access the image you are referring to by using www.example.com/images/pp_4.png. You need to know where you are placing your images and if they have been uploaded successfully to the server. Then use your HTML code to access those images and it should work.